# SQL Exception(sql Code)(sqlState 22021 ) thrown due to ERROR :invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8":0xa2

Tags: postgresql, csv, parsing

I am using a CSV parser to get data into PostgreSQL from S3. I am getting this error:

```
SQL Exception(sql Code)(sqlState 22021 ) thrown due to ERROR :invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8":0xa2
```

I am using Windows Server OS. So how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the PostgreSQL parameter `client_encoding` to the encoding of the characters in your CSV file.  Since you are on Windows, that might be

```
SET client_encoding = WIN1252;
```